# Detect form onchange and which form elements had change at once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to detect form onchange using jQuery

But, can I get specific changed elements while form onchange detected?

```
$(document.forms['form-id']).change(function () {
   if (element1 changed) {
     do something
   }
   if (element2 changed) {
     do something
   }
});
```

Non-jQuery solution are welcome :)

Comment: Use `change` event listener on the specific element, for example `<input>`, not on the `<form>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The target property can be the element that registered for the event or a descendant of it. You can check e.target.

```
$(document.forms['form-id']).change(function (e) {
   console.log(e.target)
});
```